# How do I make links open in parent frame using a Content Editor Web Part with iframes?

Tags: iframe, web-parts, sharepoint-2007

I need to have the links within my Content Editor Web Part open in the parent frame.  The links are a part of the page the iframe is loading.  I am editing the Home Page of the SharePoint site and cannot add a  tag to the page.  Here is my code:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width: 800; height:200; position:absolute; left:-170px; top:0px;">
<iframe src="/News/Pages/Default.aspx#OuterZoneTable" style="overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:550;" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe></div>
```

The widths and heights are different because I am offsetting the page to show a particular location in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something about your requirements, wouldn't a [`TARGET` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534659%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) set to `_top` (or `_parent`) on your anchors be sufficient?

You'd need to edit the HTML source to accomplish this, so maybe you're asking if there's a way to set that behavior using the Content Editor WYSIWYG controls -- which I don't believe there is.

Another idea would be to use scripting to set the attribute values via the DOM. For example, if you had jQuery in play on your page of links, you could do something like:

```
$("#OuterZoneTable>a").attr("target","_top");
```

That example assumes the links you want to change are contained in an element with the HTML id of "OuterZoneTable".

Comment: It does look like I will need to do some javascript to enable opening in the parent frame like you said, thanks.